# How to set the particular value to any pixel in java?

Tags: java, pixel, grayscale

Actually I'm working on some image processing project and got struck somewhere. I have to convert the colored image to grey scale and for this i have extracted the values of *RED*, *GREEN*, *BLUE* component of a pixel using `GETRGB()` n now I want to set the *RGB* value of that pixel equal to the average of its *RGB* component. The *RGB* components are stored in INT variables respectively, so can u help me to set the average of this *RGB* components to the original pixel value??
The part of the code is :

```
           rgbArray=new int[w*h];
           buffer.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, rgbArray , 0,width );
           int a,r,g,b; 
           for(int i = 0 ; i<w*h; i++)
            { 
              r = (0x00ff0000 & rgbArray[i]) >> 16;
              g = (0x0000ff00 & rgbArray[i]) >> 8;
              b = (0x000000ff & rgbArray[i]);
              rgbArray[i] = (r+g+b)/3;
            }
           buffer.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, rgbArray , 0,width);
```

but this is not giving me a grey image. Can u tell where i am doing a mistake.

Comment: Could you give us more context?  A lot more context?  For example, the code for your structures that you're trying to add this feature to would be nice.

Comment: Since you tagged this `greyscale`, here's a remark: the human eye is not equally sensitive to red, green and blue, so averaging the three components will not give you a proper grayscale image.

Comment: yup.. Sure.. I hav edited my question..

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want to do. If you are trying to produce a gray color I suggest referring to the following page: http://www.tayloredmktg.com/rgb/ which shows rgb codes for different shades of gray.

If you are trying to get a translucent image you have to use the alpha channel (RGBA commands) in java. You can also get translucency by compositing the underlying image with your current image in special ways but that is MUCH harder than using alpha channel.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not pack the grayscale level back into each color component. Also, as I said in my comment to the question, conversion to grayscale needs to consider the human eye's sensitivity to each color component. A typical formula for obtaining the gray level is

```
G = 0.30 * R + 0.59 * G + 0.11 * B
```

as [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Converting_color_to_grayscale) states.

So your `for` loop should look like this:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i<w*h; i++)
{
    a = (0xff000000 & rgbArray[i]);
    r = (0x00ff0000 & rgbArray[i]) >> 16;
    g = (0x0000ff00 & rgbArray[i]) >> 8;
    b = (0x000000ff & rgbArray[i]);
    int gray = (int)(0.30 * r + 0.59 * g + 0.11 * b);
    if ( gray < 0 ) gray = 0;
    if ( gray > 255 ) gray = 255;
    rgbArray[i] = a | ( gray << 16 ) | ( gray << 8 ) | gray;
}
```

You can, of course, declare `gray` outside of the loop, like you did with `r`, etc.

Comment: @lhaballpti: you mean to say that my code should be:                                                          rgbArray=new int[w*h];
buffer.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, rgbArray , 0,width );
int a,r,g,b; 
for(int i = 0 ; i<w*h; i++)
   { 
      r = (0x00ff0000 & rgbArray[i]) >> 16;
      g = (0x0000ff00 & rgbArray[i]) >> 8;
      b = (0x000000ff & rgbArray[i]);
      rgbArray[i] = (int) (0.30 * r + 0.59 * g + 0.11 * b);
     }
    buffer.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, rgbArray , 0,width);

Comment: @lhaballpti: Still i am not getting the correct answer. :( according to your above edited code the RED and GREEN are coming out to be correct but the BLUE color component is always coming to be 255. I mean to say that instead of image turning to gray, it is being turned to somewhat bluish in color...

Comment: @lhaballpti: when i am doing 'rgbArray[i] =( gray << 16 ) | ( gray << 8 ) | gray;'  instead of 'rgbArray[i] = a | ( gray << 16 ) | ( gray << 8 ) | gray;' i.e when i am removing a componete then i am getting the grey-scale image.. Can u explain this??

Comment: @Arizvi: what format is the output image? How are you setting the output's pixel data after the conversion?